# Android, How to delay Broadcast Receiver for a while?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, delay

In my app there are 2 buttons. With one button; output is "A", with both buttons the output is "B".

I use broadcast receiver to get appropriate data. But there is a problem with pressing 2 buttons. Because i sometimes don't press each buttons at the same time. So receiver gets "A" firstly then "B". I think i can solve this problem with delaying receiver for a while. But how?
My broadcast code is below. I have tried `Thread.sleep(100);` but it doesn't work.

```
       String word="";
       IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.MAIN");
       broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                   e.printStackTrace();
                }
                word=intent.getExtras().getString("keyboard");

             }

        };
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a delay in the Broadcast receiver, create a delay before sending the broadcast.
In the button handlers, use some boolean variables to check button clicks, and use [handler.postDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29)
to call `sendBroadcast`. You can also add some checks to make sure that only one broadcast is sent during subsequent clicks

Comment: can you suggest any example or tutorial or link?

Answer (score 0):

You can not operate on two intents inside a BroadcastReceiver. The way it works is that you receive one intent, you perform your operation on it (serially) and then finish it until you receive next intent. Your solution does not work because you put the thread in sleep, and in this duration of course you can't get the next bcasted intent either, until the sleep period is over, which then you finish processing the current intent, and then you receive the next one.

I am not sure what is your scenario, but you need to somehow keep the state in your code, so your code knows you already have received the first intent. For example you can define a variable outside of broadcastReceiver, which keeps track of the intents received so far, and then inside the receiver, you can check the state, and based on whether input A already is received or not you can operate.

Answer (score 0):

You can send broadcast delayed, like use this wrap function.

```
public static void sendBroadcastDelayed(Context context, Intent intent, long delay) {
    Handle handler = new Handle();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @override
        public void run() {
            context.sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    }, delay);
}
```